# Primefaces FileUpload Get File Extension

Tags: primefaces

I'm using the primefaces fileUpload component and then I inspect the FileUploadEvent.getFile but I don't see a way to reliably get the extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getFile() returns an org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile object which has a method getFileName to return the file name. Then you can get the extension from the filename.

```
UploadedFile tfile = event.getFile();
String str = tfile.getFileName();
String ext = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.'), str.length());
```

Comment: You may also want to check your String actually contains a '.' so you don't get an error.

Comment: The StringUtils class of the springframework provides a convenience method for that:

org.springframework.util.StringUtils.getFilenameExtension("test.txt") => txt

Answer (score 3):

Another option using org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

```
UploadedFile tfile = event.getFile();
String str = tfile.getFileName();
String prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(str);
String suffix = FilenameUtils.getExtension(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a split, eliminating the point. Remember that there may be more than one point in the title of the file, you must restore the last parameter of the split return.

```
    UploadedFile file = e.getFile();
    String [] nameFile= file.getFileName().split("[.]");
    String extension= nameFile[nameFile.length-1];
```